# Angular JS object is passed to one function but not another

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object in Angular that is being used in the library I'm using. When I wrote a new function I cannot pass this same object. I'm not sure why.

The object is called `person`. The function I'm trying to write is called clickLike. I literally just want the same thing to happen whether someone clicks or swipes right. You can see the dev site here: 
http://430designs.com/xperience/black-label-app/deck.php

Here's the entire controller.js file:

```
angular.module('black-label', ['ngTouch', 'ngSwippy'])
.controller('MainController', function($scope, $timeout, $window) {
    $scope.cardsCollection = [
      {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/thor_01.jpg',
          collection: 'thoroughbred',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/thor_02.jpg',
          collection: 'thoroughbred',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/thor_03.jpg',
          collection: 'thoroughbred',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/thor_04.jpg',
          collection: 'thoroughbred',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/thor_05.jpg',
          collection: 'thoroughbred',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/thor_06.jpg',
          collection: 'thoroughbred',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/rhap_01.jpg',
          collection: 'rhapsody',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/rhap_02.jpg',
          collection: 'rhapsody',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/rhap_03.jpg',
          collection: 'rhapsody',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/rhap_04.jpg',
          collection: 'rhapsody',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/rhap_05.jpg',
          collection: 'rhapsody',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/rhap_06.jpg',
          collection: 'rhapsody',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/cha_01.jpg',
          collection: 'chalet',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/cha_02.jpg',
          collection: 'chalet',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/cha_03.jpg',
          collection: 'chalet',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/cha_04.jpg',
          collection: 'chalet',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/cha_05.jpg',
          collection: 'chalet',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/cha_06.jpg',
          collection: 'chalet',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/mod_01.jpg',
          collection: 'modern',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/mod_02.jpg',
          collection: 'modern',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/mod_03.jpg',
          collection: 'modern',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/mod_04.jpg',
          collection: 'modern',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/mod_05.jpg',
          collection: 'modern',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/mod_06.jpg',
          collection: 'modern',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/ind_01.jpg',
          collection: 'indulgence',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/ind_02.jpg',
          collection: 'indulgence',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/ind_03.jpg',
          collection: 'indulgence',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/ind_04.jpg',
          collection: 'indulgence',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/ind_05.jpg',
          collection: 'indulgence',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/ind_06.jpg',
          collection: 'indulgence',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/cnt_01.jpg',
          collection: 'center-stage',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/cnt_02.jpg',
          collection: 'center-stage',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/cnt_03.jpg',
          collection: 'center-stage',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/cnt_04.jpg',
          collection: 'center-stage',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/cnt_05.jpg',
          collection: 'center-stage',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/cnt_06.jpg',
          collection: 'center-stage',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/vin_01.jpg',
          collection: 'vineyard',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/vin_02.jpg',
          collection: 'vineyard',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/vin_03.jpg',
          collection: 'vineyard',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/vin_04.jpg',
          collection: 'vineyard',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/vin_05.jpg',
          collection: 'vineyard',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/vin_06.jpg',
          collection: 'vineyard',
      }, 
    ];

    // Do the shuffle
    var shuffleArray = function(array) {
        var m = array.length,
            t, i;
        // While there remain elements to shuffle
        while (m) {
            // Pick a remaining element
            i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);
            // And swap it with the current element.
            t = array[m];
            array[m] = array[i];
            array[i] = t;
        }
        return array;
    };
    $scope.deck = shuffleArray($scope.cardsCollection);

    $scope.myCustomFunction = function() {
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.clickedTimes = $scope.clickedTimes + 1;
        $scope.actions.unshift({ name: 'Click on item' });
      });
    };

    $scope.count = 0;
    $scope.showinfo = false;
    $scope.clickedTimes = 0;
    $scope.actions = [];
    $scope.picks = [];
    var counterRight = 0;
    var counterLeft = 0;

    $scope.swipeend = function() {
        $scope.actions.unshift({ name: 'Collection Empty' });
        $window.location.href = 'theme-default.html';
    }; //endswipeend

    $scope.swipeLeft = function(person) {
        //Essentially do nothing
        $scope.actions.unshift({ name: 'Left swipe' });
        $('.circle.x').addClass('dislike');
        $('.circle.x').removeClass('dislike');
        $(this).each(function() {
            return counterLeft++;
        });
    }; //end swipeLeft

    $scope.swipeRight = function(person) {
      $scope.actions.unshift({ name: 'Right swipe' });

      // Count the number of right swipes
      $(this).each(function() {
          return counterRight++;
      });
      // Checking the circles
      $('.circle').each(function() {
          if (!$(this).hasClass('checked')) {
              $(this).addClass('checked');
              return false;
          }
      });

      $('.icon-like').addClass('liked');
      $('.icon-like').removeClass('liked');

      $scope.picks.push(person.collection);
      // console.log('Picks: ' + $scope.picks);
      // console.log("Counter: " + counterRight);
      if (counterRight === 4) {
          // Calculate and store the frequency of each swipe
          var frequency = $scope.picks.reduce(function(frequency, swipe) {
              var sofar = frequency[swipe];
              if (!sofar) {
                  frequency[swipe] = 1;
              } else {
                  frequency[swipe] = frequency[swipe] + 1;
              }
              return frequency;
          }, {});

          var max = Math.max.apply(null, Object.values(frequency)); // most frequent
          // find key for the most frequent value
          var winner = Object.keys(frequency).find(element => frequency[element] == max);
          $window.location.href = 'theme-' + winner + '.html';

      } //end 4 swipes
    }; //end swipeRight

    $scope.clickLike = function() {
      $scope.swipeRight();
    }; //clickLike
});
```

If I'm leaving anything out please let me know.

Thanks in advance everyone!

UPDATE: 
HTML file for the deck

```
<div class="ng-swippy noselect">
<div person="person" swipe-directive="swipe-directive" ng-repeat="person in peopleToShow" class="content-wrapper swipable-card">
  <div class="card">
      <div style="background: url({{person.thumbnail}}) no-repeat 50% 15%" class="photo-item"></div>
      <div class="know-label">{{labelOk ? labelOk : "YES"}}</div>
      <div class="dontknow-label">{{labelNegative ? labelNegative : "NO"}}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="progress-stats" ng-if="data">
      <div class="card-shown">
          <div class="card-shown-text">{{person.collection}}</div>
          <div class="card-shown-number">{{person.subtitle}}</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-number">{{collection.length - (collection.indexOf(person))}}/{{collection.length}}&nbsp;
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container like-dislike" >
    <div class="circle x" ng-click="$parent.$parent.clickDisike()"></div>
    <div class="icon-like" ng-click="$parent.$parent.clickLike()"></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</div><!-- end person-->
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Comment: your `$scope.swipeRight()` function requires an object as parameter. You have to supply when you call

Comment: @azad, you're right. I've been passing the `person` object as in the regular swipeRight. However, when I do that I get an error when I click on the heart. I've added that object back to my function. But I'm not sure why it's not getting passed on this particular function. It's always available for the swipeRight and swipeLeft functions above.

Comment: without passing the object how it available inside the function?

Comment: That's what I'm not sure about. I can't find where the object is being set originally. I'm still very new to Angular. So I'm not sure if this is an Angular thing or not.

Comment: where is your person object?

Comment: I guess that's my next major problem. I'm not 100% sure honestly. If you set a breakpoint in controller.js on line 198 and then swipe one of the images right, you'll be able to see the person object. I just don't know where it's coming from :(

Comment: ok the `cardsCollection` object is the one you getting as `person` object you can use it.

Comment: The `person` object might be coming from DOM bindings. It will be helpful and easy to understand if you can add some html code and remove some elements from the `cardsCollection` object

Comment: @me_digvijay, I added the HTML. I do see a `person="person"` in the 2nd element. I tried doing a search for that in the library's code, but came up empty. So if it is indeed coming from that, why can't I use that object globally?